# Is it possible to load Bitmap from sd card without decoding?

Tags: android, sd-card

Is there any way to save bitmap to sd card and then load it from there without using decode? 
I want to decode bitmaps only once and then use decoded files on sd card, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a .bmp formatted image with no compression.  You'd still need to call decode to open it, but it will be a pretty much instant call since you aren't compressed.  It will lead to huge files though-  4 bytes per pixel, plus some headers.